# how recover user profile plugin joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla3.0

I wanted to edit the plugin in the object adding additional fields. But the guide that I've followed was for an older version of Joomla. Now I want recover the plugin because everything is missed up. How can I do that?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: Post some code and an error and we can help you solve, but as is you'll need to find and pay a specialist in Joomla.